# Using Script.Util.HttpRequest returns failure

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ssjs

I am trying to make a request using `Script.Util.HttpRequest` instead of HTTP.Post, as I will need to use the PATCH request type in a subsequent call.

In my test POST call I get the following error:

```
Fatal error, failed to send contacts successfully to system
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]
```

The code is as follows:

```
try {

    var payload = {
      "grant_type":"Basic " + ENCODED_PASS
    };
    var headerNames = ['grant_type'];
    var headerValues = ['Basic ' + ENCODED_PASS];

    var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest("https://api-test.free.beeceptor.com");
    req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
    req.retries = 2;
    req.continueOnError = true;
    req.contentType = "application/json";
    req.setHeader(headerNames,headerValues);
    req.method = "POST";
    req.postData = Stringify(payload);

    var resp = req.send();
    Platform.Response.Write("Return header: "+resp.StatusCode +"<br>");
    Platform.Response.Write("Content:<br/ >"+resp.content +"");

} catch (e) {
    Write("Fatal error, failed to send contacts successfully to system<br>");  
    Write(e);  

}
```

Comment: I believe the issue is with your `headerNames` and `headerValues` variables. These cannot be arrays. If you have multiple headers/values to place, you would do multiple `setHeader` actions. E.g. `req.setHeader('header1','header1Val');  req.setHeader('header2','header2Val)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moved to answer from comments for better visibility:

I believe the issue is with your `headerNames` and `headerValues` variables.

These cannot be arrays. If you have multiple headers/values to place, you would do multiple `setHeader` actions.

E.g.

```
req.setHeader('header1','header1Val'); 
req.setHeader('header2','header2Val);
```